# When the object will be released assigning a strong reference to a weak reference, using ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

if for example we have 2 object with an NSString property, one is weak and one is strong like this

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
@property (weak) NSString *weakString;
@end


@interface Class2 : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *strongString;
@end
```

then doing this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"bla"];

Class2 *c2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];
c2.strongString = string;

string = nil;

Class1 *c1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
c1.weakString = c2.strongString;

c2.strongString = nil;
```

or even

```
c2 = nil;
```

and then what c1.weakString contains ?

assigning string to strongString call a retain on string, assigning string to nil send the first release to the string, assigning strongString to weakString doesn't change the retain count, then assigning nil to strongString send the second release to string or even assigning nil to c2, so releasing c2 should send the second release to string and so now the retainCount of weakString (and so string) should be zero and then released so weakString zeroed having nil if we try to access it

but 'weakString' still containing "bla" so the original string object, WHY?

Comment: as long as you have at least one strong reference, an object should not be deallocated/set to `nil`.

Comment: I know but after assigning nil to the strongString and string, the strong referense shouldn't exist anymore, or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, if that's your concern: deallocation does not happen immediately. It may be delayed slightly.

Comment: the deallocation happen at the next run loop cycle, but the thing is that is not happening at all, but if you skip the strong assignement the deallocation happen immediatelly

Comment: @Rob I did it and the behaviour doesn't change

Comment: the key is assigning the strong property to the weak property, because assignining string directly to weakString rather that assing strongWeak the behaviour is the one that I was expecting

Answer (score 2):

`NSString` is a class cluster and does some unintuitive optimizations in the background. If you repeat your test with some custom `NSObject` subclass rather than `NSString`, it will behave more like you're expecting.

Imagine the following variation on your example:

```
@interface MyTestObject : NSObject
@end

@interface Class1 : NSObject
@property (weak) NSString *weakString;
@property (weak) MyTestObject *weakObject;
@end

@interface Class2 : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *strongString;
@property (strong) MyTestObject *strongObject;
@end
```

And then consider:

```
Class2 *c2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];
Class1 *c1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];

@autoreleasepool {
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"bla"];
    MyTestObject *object = [[MyTestObject alloc] init];

    c2.strongString = string;
    c2.strongObject = object;

    string = nil;
    object = nil;

    c1.weakString = c2.strongString;
    c1.weakObject = c2.strongObject;

    c2.strongString = nil;
    c2.strongObject = nil;
}

NSLog(@"c1.weakString = %@", c1.weakString);
NSLog(@"c1.weakObject = %@", c1.weakObject);
```

You'd expect both `weakString` and `weakObject` to be `nil`, but only `weakObject` is. This is a result of some internal implementation optimizations going on in the `NSString` class.

Comment: Thanks, I did the test and it worked as expected, so seems that an object assigned to a property strong, even the property has been setted to nil, is not releases until the autorelease pool is not drained. but when actually the current autorelease pool is drained?

Comment: @Manu I'm not at all clear as to when, if ever, the `weak` `NSString` property is `nil`-ed. I modified the above example, making `c1` and `c2` class properties of my view controller, and when I checked the `weak` properties of `c1` much later, the `weakString` was still reporting a value even though the app had long since removed any strong references to it. Bottom line, I wouldn't rely upon a `weak` reference to a `NSString` to report `nil` even after your app no longer has any `strong` references to it.

Comment: A weak variable is set to nil when the object is deallocated. In the NSString case, a string object may not be deallocated because it is an immortal constant string. In other cases, an object may not be deallocated yet because it has been autoreleased and that autorelease pool has not yet been drained.

Answer (score 0):

Deallocation doesn't happen immediately.

Put your implementation in `@autoreleasepool` and then print weakString, it would be nil.

(Use `initWithFormat` for string initialization instead of redundant `initWithString`)

```
Class2 *c2 = nil;
Class1 *c1 = nil;

@autoreleasepool {
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"bla"];

    c2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];
    c2.strongString = string;

    string = nil;

    c1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
    c1.weakString = c2.strongString;

    c2.strongString = nil;
}

NSLog(@"str = %@", c1.weakString);
```

OUTPUT : **str = (null)**

Now, if you change weakString property to 'strong' instead of 'weak'

```
@property (strong) NSString *weakString;
```

OUTPUT : **str = bla**

Answer (score 0):

1. the retain count you calculated is right.
2. ARC is just adding retain/release code at compile time for you ,so the basic rule is same as manual management memory. when retain count is zero, it will be dealloced at once.
3. the example above is an special case: NSString is under special memory managed for performance . the string content is immutable. Same string content  will point to the same memory address to not duplicate multi-times. the NSString retain count is too big to release.